# SQL Server - Q&A Engine

Tags: sql

I'm investigating the possibility of writing a web-based question and answers engine to assist my girlfriend in her line of work.

What I mean by "question and answers" engine is, that the database (and ultimately user interface) can present many styles of question to an end user - not specifically multiple choice, the questions could be "fill in the blank(s)" or "sqrt(189) equals" or "change the words in the paragraph" or a "word-search" style question with many correct answers.

As a more specific example, if a question was "fill in the missing words: '*the **____** brown **____** jumps over the ____ dog*'" and the user is presented with various answers. Likewise, another specific answer could be "*list as many words you can make from the word: 'antidisestablishmentarianism'*".

Having done some searches already on stackoverflow, there have been some similar questions raised however none seemed to fit the mould of what I'm wanting.

As I see it, I can have a single questions table...

```
TABLE Questions
    QuestionID UNIQUE INT
    Question NTEXT // The question text (could include markup for web)
    Options NTEXT // Could be a CSV list of possible options (for multi-choice type questions)   
    QuestionTypeID INT // ID of the question type record (more for the user-interface)

TABLE QuestionTypes
    QuestionTypeID UNIQUE INT
    Description NVARCHAR(100)

TABLE Answers
    AnswerID UNIQUE INT
    UserID INT  // Related User record 
    QuestionID INT // Related Question record
    Answers NTEXT // Could this be a CSV list of answers??
```

I can see how the above would work for very simple, single or multiple choice answers but I'm not sure how it would work for different styles of question.

Another thought I had was having different tables handling different QuestionTypeID values, for example:

```
TABLE QuestionType1 // Table styled to question type 1
    QuestionType1ID UNIQUE INT
    QuestionID INT // Related question record
    ...

TABLE QuestionType2 // Table styled to question type 2
    QuestionType2ID UNIQUE INT
    QuestionID INT // Related question record
    ...
```

But I can't really see how this would work. Am I thinking about this or approaching it in the wrong way?

I'd appreciate any help (if the question makes sense in the first place)!

Regards,
K

Comment: Whats related to the C# here?

Comment: Sorry, I should have adjusted the title and the tags. I was going to include a few C# classes wrapping the SQL stuff but decided against it. Will update. Sorry

Comment: `QuestionType2ID`? My brain hurts trying to think about that logically.

Comment: Also, please forget that you have ever heard of data types like `NTEXT`. They're deprecated, just stop using them.